# What's the procedure of breaking ekadashi fast according to scriptures?

Tags: rituals, fasting, ekadashi

At what time on dwadashi, parana should be observed?

What should be eaten to break the fast?

Can ekadashi be not broken during hari vasara?

Comment: Check the parana times in the Drikpanchang website for your residing place. Fast has to be broken within the parana time strictly. You can eat anything that you have not eaten during the fasting day. For example a Nirjala fast can be broken by just consuming water. But better consume things that have grains and salt.

Answer (score 3):

##### The  Ekādaśī Fasts must be broken on the Dvādaśī.

[Chapter 37](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365614.html) - Padma Purāṇa

> 75. to 78. O best brāhmaṇa, all rivers (like) Gaṅgā, Sarasvatī, Tāpī, Yamunā, Śatadrukā, Candrabhāgā, Vitastā, so also ponds, deep lakes,
>     all seas go there on the Ekādaśī (day for) keeping awake (in honor)
>     of Viṣṇu. These men are desirable to gods, being delighted by the musical
>     instrument like the lute, dance and sing (at the time of) keeping
>     awake (in honor) of Viṣṇu. **In this way having kept awake, having
>     worshipped great Viṣṇu, he should, along with Viṣṇu’s devotees, break
>     his fast on the Dvādaśī (day).**

[Chapter CXXIII](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122603.html) - Garuḍa Purāṇa

> The performance of the Ekadasi Vrata is imperatively obligatory on
> all, a breach being sinful and degrading. A man shall observe a fast
> on the eleventh day of the fortnight, whether light or dark, inasmuch
> as it tends to absolve him of all sins, precludes the chance of his
> ever visiting the shades of Haydes and makes him entitled to the
> beatitude of the region of Vishnu. **A man observing a fast on the
> eleventh day of the fortnight, shall break it on the twelfth, and
> resume his, usual mode of living on the night of the thirteenth.**

---

##### Specific Rules about Ekadasi

> Chapter [234](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365818.html), Padma Purāṇa
>
> 17-24. Ekādaśī mixed with Daśamī should be carefully avoided. (If
> Daśamī continues) at the time of dawn (on the Ekādaśī day), it (i.e.
> the Ekādaśī) would be mixed with Daśamī. Leaving it (i.e. that Ekādaśī
> day) he should, without (further) thought, observe a fast on the pure
> (i.e. unmixed) Dvādaśī. O goddess, **if a part of Ekādaśī continues at
> the sunrise on the Trayodaśī day, then Dvādaśī remains on that day
> also. At dawn, he should perform all rites. Even if a part of Dvādaśī
> is there, breaking the fast (on that day) is recommended**. In this case,
> one should ignore even a pure Ekādaśī. There is no doubt about it.
> Even if a part of the Ekādaśī continues on the Dvādaśī when the sun
> has risen, one should ignore the entire Ekādaśī (on the previous day)
> and observe a fast on that (Dvādaśī) day. Having decided the rite like
> this, one should observe a fast on the day of (i.e. sacred to) Viṣṇu.
> Avoiding four meals, one in the evening of the first day, another in
> the morning of the last (i.e. the third) day, and two on the middle
> (i.e. the second) day, one should observe a fast. On the Daśamī day he
> should eat once (only), avoid (sexual) union with his wife, sleep on
> the ground, and should remain pure on the next day.

[Chapter 12](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371691.html) - Mārgaśīrṣa-māhātmya - Vaiṣṇava-khaṇḍa - Skanda Purāṇa

> **On the Daśamī day he should have Naktabhojana. He should fast on the Ekādaśī day. On the Dvādaśī day he should take a single meal. This is called Akhaṇḍa. By the word Nakta we mean the eighth part of the day when the sun becomes very dim. Food is taken then and not at night.**

---

#### The Complete Procedure of The Ekādaśī Fast as per the Nārada Purāṇa

[Chapter 23](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12945/page/n333/mode/2up)

The Procedure of Ekadasi Vrata

> 12. On the Dasami (tenth) day, the devotee should get up very early in the morning (and should take bath) after duly washing the teeth. With
>     purity and control over the sense-organs, he should duly bathe Vişņu
>     and worship him (according to the prescription of the Sastras).
> 13. On the Ekadasi day, one should go without food and put curbs on the sense-organs. Devoted to Narayana, he should go to bed in the
>     vicinity of Vişņu.
> 14. On the Ekadasi day, the devotee should take bath and worship Janardana duly with scents, fragrant flowers, and other things. Then
>     he should repeat as follows:
> 15. "O Pundarikáksa (Lotus-eyed God) after refraining from food today, the Ekadasi day, I shall take food the next day, O Acyuta, be my
>     refuge."
> 16. After uttering properly this Mantra of the Discusbearing lord of Devas, he should be contented in the mind, with emotional feelings and
>     devotion, dedicate fast (unto the Lord).
> 17. Maintaining the observances and the holy rites, the devoted one should keep awake in front of the Lord, singing songs, playing on
>     instruments, and listening to Puranas.
> 18. Then, he should get up in the morning on the Dvadasi day. After taking the bath duly, he should worship Vişnu keeping sense-organs
>     under control.
> 19. After bathing Janardana in Pancamrla on the Ekadasi day and in milk on the Duddafi day, O Brahmana, the devotee shall attain Sårupya
>     (sameness of form-a kind of liberation) with Hari.
> 20. "O keśava, be pleased with the observance of this holy vow. Be pleased to be gracious-looking. Please be the bestower of the vision
>     of spiritual knowledge to me, blinded as I am by the darkness of
>     ignorance."

#### `Can ekadashi be not broken during hari vasara?`

NO. Eating on Harivāsara (i.e. eleventh day) i.e. Ekādaśī is forbidden. This activity leads to hell

> 4. **One should not take food on the Ekadasi (eleventh) day in either of the fortnights (of a month). He who takes food is a sinner in this
>    world. In the other world, he shall fall into hell.**
> 5. One who is desirous of attaining the benefit of the fast, should not take four meals, viz. the night meals on the previous (Daśami day)
>    as well as following (Dvadasi day) and both the meals on the (Ekādasi)
>    day in the middle. (vide V.7 below).
> 6. The man who desires to take food on the Ekādasi day is one who seeks the enjoyment of all sins. There is no doubt about this.
> 7. **If anyone desires salvation, O leading sage, let him take only one meal on the Dasami (tenth) as well as on the Dvadasi (twelfth) day
>    (in each fortnight). He shall fully abstain from taking food on the
>    Ekadasi (Eleventh) day in both fortnights)**.
> 8. **O Brāhmaṇa, whatever sins are there, such as Brahmaņa-slaughter, etc., they abide in the cooked food on the day of Hari (i.e. the Ekadasi day).**

### `What should be eaten to break the fast?`

Obviously, food must be Sattvika and also cooked when attempting the pāraṇa. In practice (especially in our area) eating cooked rice is a must after the fast.

### `At what time on Dvādaśī, pāraṇa. should be observed?`

In practice, the Ekādaśī Fast is broken (pāraṇa) as soon as the Dvādaśī tithī begins on a given day, after duly completing the daily rites & rituals associated with the fast and normal days worship.

> 21. O leading Brähmaņa, after requesting thus to Madhava with attention and purity, he should feed the Brahmaņas according to his
>     ability. He should then give the usual Daksind.
> 22. **He should thereafter perform the five sacrifices and devoted to Närayana, restrained in speech, he should take food along with his
>     kinsmen.**

Answer (score 1):

## At what time on dwadashi, parana should be observed?

As per [Skanda Puaran,](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371691.html) the fast should be broken at eighth part (pahar) of dvadasi.

> On the Daśamī day he should have Naktabhojana. He should fast on the Ekādaśī day. On the Dvādaśī day he should take a single meal. This is called Akhaṇḍa. By the word Nakta we mean **the eighth part of the day when the sun becomes very dim. Food is taken then and not at night.**

## Can ekadashi be not broken during hari vasara?

> 92-94. Thus Lord Janārdana who is asleep said: “If a man takes cereal food on that day (i.e. eleventh day) he becomes a sinner. He may suffer from fever or excruciating pain. **Hence a sensible man should abstain from food assiduously on the Harivāsara (Ekādaśī) day** on the other occasions also. Why then should he take food on the day when he goes to sleep and on the day when he wakes up?

[Source](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc502210.html)